# Struggling with Running Sum query in SQL

Tags: sql, database, sum, window-functions, cumulative-sum

I am struggling with this query.  It is calculating the running sum correctly for the first depot but as soon as it gets to the next depot it should start at zero again for the running sum total but it continues with the previous depot's ending total, what am I doing wrong?

Here is my query, I've also added an image of the output.

```
SELECT 
    Depot
    ,WorkDayNr
    ,DayOfMonth
    ,Tons
    ,SUM (Tons) OVER (ORDER BY Depot, WorkDayNr) AS RunTotal
FROM #Final
GROUP BY Depot, WorkDayNr, DayOfMonth, Tons
ORDER BY Depot, WorkDayNr
```

[image: run]

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `partition` clause:

```
 SUM (Tons) OVER (PARTITION BY SUBGROUP ORDER BY Depot, WorkDayNr) AS RunTotal
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `partition` to the window function. The name of the columns in the resultset do not match the query, so I suspect you want `Depot` rather than `SubGrp`

```
SUM (Tons) OVER (PARTITION BY Depot ORDER BY WorkDayNr) AS RunTotal
```

Also, I don't see the point for using aggregation in this query. You seem to be confusing aggregate function (`SUM()` without an `OVER()` clause), which require aggregation, with window function. As far as concerns, your query should just be:

```
SELECT 
    Depot,
    WorkDayNr,
    DayOfMonth,
    Tons,
    SUM (Tons) OVER (PARTITION BY Depot ORDER BY WorkDayNr) AS RunTotal
FROM #Final
ORDER BY Depot, WorkDayNr
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be partitioning by depot:

```
SELECT 
    Depot,
    WorkDayNr,
    DayOfMonth,
    Tons,
    SUM(Tons) OVER (PARTITION BY Depot ORDER BY WorkDayNr) AS RunTotal
FROM #Final
ORDER BY
    Depot,
    WorkDayNr;
```

Also note that your `GROUP BY` clause is probably superfluous and unnecessary because you aren't actually selecting any aggregates.  When using `SUM` as an analytic function, the aggregation is already rolled up into it, without needing to use `GROUP BY`.